# Error converting data type varchar to float Error- Sum with a negative number

Tags: sql

I have the following statement which adds a negative sign and multiplies a number by 100 but if fails for Error converting data type varchar to float. any help is appreciated. Thanks!

```
 '-' +  (select Sum (isnull(CAST(Quantity*100  as float),0)) from Tables
```

Answer (score 0):

The '+' operator is for strings. You have an explicitly cast float, so that'll fail.

```
(select -1.0*Sum (isnull(CAST(Quantity*100  as float),0)) from Tables
```

Multiplying by negative one (-1.0, not -1, so you don't turn it into an integer) should get you where you need to be. Unless, of course, the sum of Quantity is a negative number, in which case, this will give you a positive value. Which also might be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

We just need to add the negative symbol before the sub query as below

```
-(select Sum (isnull(CAST(Quantity*100  as float),0)) from Tables
```